# Android hide the current call

Tags: java, android, mobile, root

How can I hide the current call as soon as I received a call?
Ie it is necessary that during a call the phone application minimized.
Can it be done using the root?

Comment: I didn't really get what you want to do, but you can use WindowManager to add a View when a call comes. That's how you can have an effect on incoming call screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I use when a call comes in, but unfortunately the screen sometimes appear later Intent triggered earlier.
Maybe you can somehow find out is minimized or maximized window of a phone call?